# Prove that the determinant is greater than $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix whose diagonal entries are strictly positive and off-diagonal entries are negative. The sum of the entries on each column is $1$. Prove that $\det(A) > 1$.

I think to find all of eigenvalue to prove the determinant is greater than $1$ but I only get $1$ as eigenvalue.

Comment: Clarification : All diagonal entries are positive, and all non-diagonal entries are negative, is that right?

Comment: By "the other", you mean all off-diagonal entries are negative? (And, negative, not merely non-positive?)

Comment: Write down the equation $Ax = \lambda x$ for an eigenvalue $\lambda$, and consider $i'$ such that $|x_{i'}| = max_{i=1 \to n} |x_i|$, now try to find some inequalities by taking the modulus and using the conditions on the entries of $A$.

Comment: The determinant is the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the columns of the matrix. Since each column adds up to $1$, they must be on the hyperplane $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=1$. The condition on the signs forces them to be on the external cones at the vertices of the simplex formed in that hyperplane by the points $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$. By external cones, I mean the cones formed by extending the facets of the simplex beyond the vertex. Therefore the parallelepiped spanned by the columns of the matrix contains the parallelepiped spanned by $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$. The latter has volume $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_{ij}$ be the entries of the matrix. Then $a_{ii}=1+\sum_j|a_{ij}|$ since the other terms in the same column are negative.

Now consider $Ax=\lambda x$, $$\lambda x_j=\sum_ia_{ij}x_i=a_{jj}x_j+\sum_{i\ne j}a_{ij}x_i$$ so if we pick the largest coefficient of $x$, say $\alpha=x_k$, then $$|\lambda-a_{kk}||\alpha|\le\sum_{i\ne k}|a_{ik}||x_i|\le\sum_{i\ne k}|a_{ik}| |\alpha|=(a_{kk}-1)|\alpha|$$ $$\therefore\quad |\lambda-a_{kk}|\le a_{kk}-1$$ in particular $1\le\lambda$ (or $\mathrm{Re}(\lambda)\ge1$ if complex). So the determinant, as the product of the eigenvalues, is larger than $1$. (Note: $\lambda\bar{\lambda}=|\lambda|^2\ge1$.)

The general result along these lines is [Gershgorin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).